# Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setFilterChains'

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, keycloak

Unable to configure web security in Spring Boot 3 for Keycloak

```
@EnableMethodSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig {
}

com.c4_soft.springaddons.security.oauth2.config.SpringAddonsSecurityProperties$IssuerProperties.getLocation()" is null
```

https://pastebin.com/Psb6sdsJ

EDIT 1: build.gradle

```
// spring
implementation(libs.spring.security.config)
// implementation(libs.spring.boot.starter.security)
implementation group: 'com.c4-soft.springaddons', name: 'spring-addons-webmvc-core', version: '6.0.9'
implementation group: 'com.c4-soft.springaddons', name: 'spring-addons-webmvc-jwt-resource-server', version: '6.0.9'

implementation(libs.spring.boot.starter.oauth2.client)
// implementation(libs.spring.security.oauth2.resource.server)
```

EDIT 2:

```
com.c4-soft.springaddons.security.issuers[0].location=http://localhost:8080/realms/master
com.c4-soft.springaddons.security.issuers[0].authorities.claims=realm_access.roles,resource_access.spring-addons-public.roles,resource_access.spring-addons-confidential.roles
com.c4-soft.springaddons.security.cors[0].path=/fa/**
com.c4-soft.springaddons.security.permit-all=/actuator/health/readiness,/actuator/health/liveness
#explore for more with your IDE auto completion with com.c4-soft.springaddons.security.

spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.issuer-uri=http://localhost:8080/realms/master
spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.jwk-set-uri=http://localhost:8080/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/certs
```

EDIT 3:

```
@EnableMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig {

}
```

Comment: Are you sure the error is still the same after you added `com.c4-soft.springaddons.security`? On which ports are started Keycloak and your Spring app (because both start on 8080 by default and I can't see your config to change that)

Comment: Yes. Keycloak on 8080 - Keycloak 20.0.2 on JVM (powered by Quarkus 2.13.3.Final) started in 11.868s. Listening on: http://0.0.0.0:8080

Comment: Spring Boot App on 7650

Comment: And what is your version of Spring boot?

Comment: Spring Boot 3.0.1, Running with Spring Boot v3.0.1, Spring v6.0.3, using Java 19.0.1

Comment: Is your project available somewhere? I don't understand how location can be null with the properties you expose.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250676/discussion-between-user352290-and-ch4mp).

Answer (score 0):

You did not set properties correctly. Check your `application.properties` (or yaml)

As per main [README](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons) and [tutorials](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials)

```
com.c4-soft.springaddons.security.issuers[0].location=https://localhost:8080/realms/master
com.c4-soft.springaddons.security.issuers[0].authorities.claims=realm_access.roles,resource_access.spring-addons-public.roles,resource_access.spring-addons-confidential.roles
com.c4-soft.springaddons.security.cors[0].path=/greet/**
com.c4-soft.springaddons.security.permit-all=/actuator/health/readiness,/actuator/health/liveness
#explore for more with your IDE auto completion with com.c4-soft.springaddons.security.
```

## edit

`spring-addons-webmvc-core` is a transitive dependency of `spring-addons-webmvc-jwt-resource-server`. You don't need to declare it.

You don't need `spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver` properties with `spring-addons-webmvc-jwt-resource-server` (but it shouldn't be a problem).

Comment: i've used the configuration mentioned over here at https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials/resource-server_with_jwtauthenticationtoken for authentication using JWT which is different than what you have proposed above. The above config doesn't work as well

Comment: You are referring to a tutorial using `spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server` with a configuration class and an exception letting me think that you are using `spring-addons-webmvc-jwt-resource-server`. Add your dependencies and properties to your question. Also specify which authorization-server you are using, on which host, which port and if it served over HTTP or HTTPS

Comment: I am using http version of the keycloak 20.0.2, started using "kc.sh start-dev"